# How to convert array into string without comma and separated by space in javascript without concatenation?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I know you can do this through looping through elements of array and concatenating. But I'm looking for one-liner solutions. toString() and join() returns string with elements separated by commas.
For example,

```
var array = ['apple', 'tree'];
var toString = array.toString()    # Will return 'apple,tree' instead of 'apple tree', same for join() method
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

When you call `join` without any argument being passed, `,`(comma) is taken as default and `toString` internally calls `join` without any argument being passed.

So, pass your own separator.

```
var str = array.join(' '); //'apple tree'
// separator ---------^
```

[MDN on Array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: its amazing how many times `console.log()` makes you realize a function doesn't do exactly what you expect...

Comment: is there a way to display [apple] [tree] instead?

Answer (score 5):

pass a delimiter in to `join`.

```
['apple', 'tree'].join(' '); // 'apple tree'
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the Array.join() method. Trim to remove any unnecessary whitespaces.

`var newStr = array.join(' ').trim()`

Comment: What if we just do array.join(''). So there is no need to trim.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `.join(' ')`.

However, if the Array contains zero-length objects like `null`, the following code would avoid multiple spaces:

`arr.filter(i => [i].join(" ").length > 0).join(" ");`

Here's some example usage:

```
Array.prototype.merge = function(char = " ") {
  return this.filter(i => [i].join(" ").length > 0).join(char);
};

console.log(["a", null, null, "b"].merge());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't want to use toString() or join(), you could do something like this:

```
for(let i=0;i</*Array*/.length;i++)if(/*Variable*/=="")/*Variable*/+=/*Array*/[i];else /*Variable*/+="/*Separator*/"+/*Array*/[i];
```

Separator is what to put between each item. In your case, you would change that to a space.

Answer (score 0):

You could use splice method to add space item to array

```
var array = ['apple', 'tree'];
 array.splice(1, 0, ' ')
```

And for convert array to string use built-in methode call `join()`and the output will be like you want:

```
array.join('');
// "apple tree"
```