# How do I split an variable by 4 characters with blank spaces?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a variable that saves a certain number, and i want it to split it in by 4 characters in the display

```
document.getElementById("txtFNF").innerHTML = "<br>" + value.match(/.{1,4}/g) + "<br><br>";
   for (let index = 1; index <= value.length; index++) {
      if (Number(value[value.length - index]) == 1) {
         document.getElementById("txtFNF").innerHTML += index - 1 + " - " + FNFtoString(index - 1) + "<br>";
 }
```

the code i use "value.match(/.{1,4}/g)"already splits the number in 4, but is splited by: "," i want it to be displayed splited by an blank space: " "

ex: 0000 0000 0000 0000

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert array into string without comma and separated by space in javascript without concatenation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007949/how-to-convert-array-into-string-without-comma-and-separated-by-space-in-javascr)

Answer (score 2):

When you use `"" + []` it internally calls `toString` on array which changes it to string joined by `,`

```js
console.log("" + [1,2,3,4])
```

You can use join with space ( `join(' ')` ) on your matched values to get string with spaces,

```js
console.log("0000000000000000".match(/.{1,4}/g) + "")    // internally joining by toString
console.log("0000000000000000".match(/.{1,4}/g).join(' '))
```

Or you can even use replace and capture group, replace captured group by adding a space, trim the trailing space

```js
console.log("0000000000000000".replace(/(.{1,4})/g, "$1 ").trim())
```

Comment: without trim `"0000000000000000".replace(/.{4}\B/g, "$& ")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use join method to convert comma seprated to spaces like this

```
<div id="txtFNF" class="btn--success"></div>
<script>
    let value = '12345678';
    let val = value.match(/.{1,4}/g).join(' ', ',');
    document.getElementById("txtFNF").innerHTML = "<br>" + val + "<br><br>";
    for (let index = 1; index <= value.length; index++) {
        if (Number(value[value.length - index]) == 1) {
            document.getElementById("txtFNF").innerHTML += index - 1 + " - " + FNFtoString(index - 1) + "<br>";
        }
    }
</script>
```