# How to join arguments as string with spaces inbetween?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, arraylist, discord.js

How can I take all arguments (args) in an array and combine them into one variable with spaces in-between, but infinitely and less sketchy.
I'm somewhat new to JavaScript, so I apologize if I'm missing something apperent.

```js
var keyword = (args[0]);
if (args.length == 2) {
    keyword = (args[0] + " " + args[1])
} else if (args.length == 3) {
    keyword = (args[0] + " " + args[1] + " " + args[2])
};
```

Comment: let keywords = args.join(" ");

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert array into string without comma and separated by space in javascript without concatenation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007949/how-to-convert-array-into-string-without-comma-and-separated-by-space-in-javascr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

args is an array. So you can join that array using array.join() method.

```
const keyword = args.join(' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

A more safe and straight forward approach would be:

```
function formatKeywords(...items) {
  return items.join(' ');
}
```

```js
function formatKeywords(...items) {
  return items.join(' ');
}

console.log('Handle empty args:', formatKeywords());
console.log('With args:', formatKeywords('aa', 'bb'));
```